# play framework:How to fix Compilation error:error while loading xxxClass

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I'm running a play project from others. Once I modified anything in template the error below showed.
I need to do: "play clean" and "play run" again.
How to fix it? Thank you very much!

error:
Compilation error:error while loading xxxClass, class file 'D:\workspace\xx\target\scala-2.10\classes\xxmodels\xxClass.class' is broken (class java.util.NoSuchElementException/head of empty list)

version:
play 2.2.4 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0_131)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a class B implementing an interface A. Indeed class B was in the classpath, but A wasn't, for some reasons (snapshot JARs wasn't up-to-date).
So I just removed references in the ivy cache about the JAR containing A ( `play-x.x.x/repository/cache/<groupId>/<artifactId>` ). Then that forces Play to fetch the updated JAR from the nexus, and problem disappeared.

It was similar to a standard Java "LinkageError", when an element is missing in a whole class hierarchy.